# linear algebra, geometry. values of dot products being 0

Tags: algorithm

dot means dot product.
cross means cross product.

```c
void func(vec3 origin, vec3 direction, vec3 v0, vec3 v1, vec3 v2) {

  vec3 u, v, n;
  vec3 w0;
  float r, a, b;

  u = (v1 - v0);
  v = (v2 - v0);
  n = cross(u, v);
    
  w0 = origin - v0;
  a = -dot(n, w0);
  b = dot(n, direction);
    
  r = a/b;
}
```

So, if origin, direction, v0, v1, v2 are all in the same plane a will be 0 and b will be 0.
And r = 0/0; undefined result;

Thank you very much.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: If all vec3 (mentioned) are on the same plane we will have undefined result (0/0). I would like to be confirmed if this piece of code is really udefined behaviour or if it is correct and i'm not understanding it.

Comment: If `v0`, `v1` and `v2` are in the same plane, `n` will be a vector that's perpendicular to this plane (since it comes from a cross product), hence the dimensions of `n` might be 0 in the dimensions of the plane that are not 0, what may cause the dot product that generates `a` to be 0.

Comment: Yes, a will be 0. And I was supposing direction also in the same plane of w0 which would bring b also to 0. So a = 0, b = 0, r = a/b, r = 0/0. Undefined result. Correct?

Comment: sorry. "... same plane of v0, v1, v2, which would bring b also to 0."

Comment: What problem should  this function solve?

Comment: Part of Particle System Simulator. From OpenGL Programming Guide, Ninth Edition. Page 250. If someone has this book and can help me would be thankful.

Comment: No.. What is physical sense of arguments? What are you expecting as resut?

Comment: I'm not pretty much sure if I understood correctly.

Comment: void func is bool intersect. origin is initial position of particle. direction is hmmm... direction of particle. v0, v1, v2 points of triangle that a particle should hit or not (true or false). r = a/b I don't know either what this mean, help appreciable.

Comment: There is also a test after r = a/ b. if (r < 0.0 || r > 1.0) return false;